# Nexus S and phone charger get unusually hot when plugged in

Tags: charging, samsung-nexus-s

I was using my Nexus S today and it turned off suddenly. I plugged it in to charge and saw it load to the boot splash screen, and then I went to sleep.

When I woke up 2 hours later my phone was dead. I plugged it in to the charge for another half an hour, but both the phone and the charger started getting very hot. I tested my charger and battery with another phone and both seemed to work properly without the excess heat. What happened to my phone that's causing it to heat up like this?

Comment: Probably something is messed up inside the hardware of your Nexus S?

Comment: I have that sometimes, too. Usually it's some app or android itself being rather busy. Look at Settings => Battery which one is causing it. Usually there should be `Display` at 70% consuming the most power.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a short in the USB port on the phone it can cause charging to stop and heating up to occur. I guess that's well past your warranty period, but you could still take it into a phone shop and ask about getting the port replaced. I just had that done on my Galaxy Nexus and it only took about 15 minutes once the part came in.

Answer (score 0):

There are 90% chances of it should be a hardware defect. Most probably the micro USB pins inside your Nexus might have been damaged. Also there is a possibility of your battery nearing its lifetime. Sometimes one in a million batteries die young. So I advice you to check your phone with another compatible battery.